# Report based on arbitrary data source (quantity and names of columns may change)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting

I need to export data of all columns (including technical like GUIDs for foreign keys) of an arbitrary table from a given database. I wanted to use [LocalReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.aspx) class as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138203/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-an-embedded-report-definition-without-server-or-ui), but I can't think of how to set up the report for an arbitrary data source (even quantity and names of columns may change).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like report builder (sql adhoc reporting) suit your needs instead?

Seems like you need a report to work on any table in any database.  These things seem 'hardcoded' in sql reports.

If you were to get this to work, I expect it would be by using code to generate a report definition, which I haven't a clue how to do.